# Print the metrics directly without mentioning the column names explicitly Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

I have the following code in scala:

```
import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.{AnalysisRunner, AnalyzerContext}
import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalyzerContext.successMetricsAsDataFrame
import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.{Compliance, Correlation, Size, Completeness, Mean, ApproxCountDistinct, Maximum, Minimum, Entropy, GroupingAnalyzer}

val analysisResult: AnalyzerContext = { AnalysisRunner
  // data to run the analysis on
  .onData(datasource)
  // define analyzers that compute metrics
  .addAnalyzer(Size())
  .addAnalyzer(Completeness("customerNumber"))
  .addAnalyzer(ApproxCountDistinct("customerNumber"))
  .addAnalyzer(Minimum("creditLimit"))
  .addAnalyzer(Mean("creditLimit"))
  .addAnalyzer(Maximum("creditLimit"))
  .addAnalyzer(Entropy("creditLimit"))
  .run()
}
```

I want to print the metrics directly without mentioning the column names explicitly.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear to me. Do you want to read the columns names from a config file without hard coding them?

Comment: Please add more details to the post as stat based analyzers like mean stddev entropy etc do need a column to work on excel dataset level ones. for more details you can peek into deequ cdoe as well .